# Block Level Elements Overlapping

Tags: html, css

New to HTML and CSS and trying to replicate sites to get some practice.  I'm having some trouble replicating a section on the airbnb website where it lists the explore, contact and book.  For some reason, I float the image to the left and my h3 and p tags should not overlap the image.  I've made sure to display the image as a block, but the h3 and p tags overlap and my margins won't work.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.a

Thanks

Here's the css

```
.feat-box {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 282px;
}

.feat-box h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Shift, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(57, 60, 61);
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.feat-box p {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Shift, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(57, 60, 61);
    margin-left: 10px;

}

.feat-box img {
    float: left;
    display: block;

}

.feat-box-container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Here's my html

```
<div class="feat-box-container">
                <div class="feat-box">
                    <img src="http://www.somanyfoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/contacts.png"/>
                    <h3>Explore</h3>
                    <p>Find the perfect place.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="feat-box">
                    <img src="http://www.somanyfoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/contacts.png"/>
                    <h3>Contacts</h3>
                    <p>Message hosts.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="feat-box">
                    <img src="http://www.somanyfoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/check-mark.png"/>
                    <h3>Book</h3>
                    <p>View your itinerary.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Not sure I follow, but were you looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TgHk4/?

Comment: Something like that, but the the image should be on the left and the h3 and p tags should be to the right and not underneath it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
display:inline
```

to your

```
.feat-box p
```

you might have to play around a little with the margins to get the text to align, but it fixed it for me.

If your learning CSS I'd advice installing firebug, it's an add-on that will help you better understand how CSS works.